# How to integrate Jira Atlassian with GitLab cloud?

Tags: gitlab, jira, integration

The current documentation does not match the new interfaces exactly but what I have being able to put together is displayed in the screenshots below.

What **does** work is:

- When I push a comment to GitLab a link is built and links to the properly referenced JIRA ticket.
- JIRA is added as a LHS menu item which opens link I define as **Web URL** (see below).

What **does not** work is:

- The JIRA ticket does not display the comment.

**On GitLab**

My settings keep failing the integration test and I have no idea what the problem is.

myproject > Settings > Integrations

[image]

**On JIRA CLOUD**

I have created a user as per instructions in the docs

1. https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/integrations/jira
2. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/8-13-stable/doc/project_services/jira.md

[image]

From what I can gather is if I want to comment I just have to mention a correctly formatted JIRA ticket ID and if I want to change the state of a ticket I need to set the correct Transition ID(s) which I can find in my JIRA workflow.

I am able to log in manually to JIRA with the "Gitlab Dev" user account, and post comments.

Has anyone else got this to work with the newer admin layouts?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Jira user you set up for the integration has the correct **access permission** to post comments on a Jira issue and also to transition the issue, if you’d like GitLab to also be able to do so.

Jira issue references and update comments will not work if the GitLab issue tracker is disabled.